# Card Game Program: Design

Tags: python-2.7, design-patterns

**First some background...**

I'm currently working on a "practice project" to keep up and refine my programming skills. The project is a card game system (similar to MTG and other trading card games). I currently have the following concepts implemented:

There are *Player*s that can be created/saved/loaded, which contain profile information, win/loss statistics, and a list of *Deck*s. Each *Deck* contains a list of *Cards* (they are actually instantiations of the four different *Card* types, not the abstract *Card*s themselves), which have all the attributes needed for game-play.

**The issue...**

Saving *Player*s, *Deck*s, and *Card*s is unnecessarily redundant. If there are multiple *Deck*s with the same *Card*s or multiple *Player*s with similar *Deck*s, then the program will be saving the same *Card*s over and over again. **For Example:** If *Card A* is very popular, then *Player*s will put multiple copies into multiple *Deck*s. So, the same card will be saved over and over again.

**Conceptual solution...**

The idea is that *Player*s and *Deck*s are unique, but *Card*s are from a common pool (a set or collection that everyone can use to build *Deck*s). Therefore, I have created a directory for saving/loading *Player*s and their *Deck*s and a separate directory for storing individual *Card*s that are part of a set. I would like saving and loading of *Player*s and *Deck*s to utilize *Card* IDs, which will then reference the *Card* directory for loading and instantiating the actual objects. Additionally, the reverse needs to happen upon saving (not saving the *Deck* with *Card*s, but with *Card* IDs).

**The question(s)...**

Is there a design pattern I should be utilizing to help with the saving/loading based on IDs? Should I break up *Deck*s into *Deck*s for game-play and *Deck* lists for storage? Should I created and store *PlayerProfile*s with *DeckList*s and use those to save/load *Player*s and *Deck*s?

***NOTE:*** If you would like to see the code, let me know. It's just too much to post right here.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [flyweight](http://flyweight) design pattern.  Instead of storing a full copy of whatever a card is, you're just storing something like 5C, 8D etc.  Your application should be able to "decode" that into the full object.